# ECHO historical ACCUWEATHER data JSON

Tags: php, json

I am trying to echo a decoded json data from the accuweather API for a certain location for the past 24hours. The output would be something like this "The weather in 'City' yesterday was
date:hour - temperature
date:hour - temp
.
.
.
date:hour24 - temp24

This is the data in a [JSON format](http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/328328/historical/24?apikey=GKu1AhOuGN0aAnNEMyiWgKD5fAmo4dpN).

This is my code with the var dump and attempt to echo it in a more sophisticated and tidier way.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/328328/historical/24?apikey=GKu1AhOuGN0aAnNEMyiWgKD5fAmo4dpN');

 //decode JSON to array
 $data = json_decode($json,true);

 //show data
 print_r($data);

 foreach ($data['list'] as $hour => $value) {
    echo "The temperature for the hour ". $hours ." was ". $value[Temperature]."<br/>";
    # code...
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry. I don't understand. Your text says "temperatur will be ...." but the data shows historical data. What are you trying to do? Are you trying to output the timestamp and the temperature of each historical item?

Comment: That's grammar error on my part, the temp was* I'm trying to ouput the timestamp for every hour and the temp at that time for the last 24hrs

Comment: Got it! Will post an answer below.

Comment: If you have checked the json file, I'm trying to output LocalObservationDateTime with its corresponding temperature for the last 24hours.

Comment: Is my answer correct or did I miss something?

Comment: dont post your key :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will loop through each timestamp and output the timestamp and metric value of temperature.
Not sure what you wanted, but it's an easy change if it's not correct.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/328328/historical/24?apikey=GKu1AhOuGN0aAnNEMyiWgKD5fAmo4dpN');

 //decode JSON to array
 $data = json_decode($json,true);

 //show data
 echo "<pre>";
// print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
 foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo "The temperature for the hour ". $value["LocalObservationDateTime"] ." will be ". $value["Temperature"]["Metric"]["Value"]."<br/>";
                                                                                                         //  or "Imperial"
    # code...
 }
```

EDIT to show date() function.

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo "The temperature for the hour ". date("Y-m-d H:i", $value["EpochTime"]) ." will be ". $value["Temperature"]["Metric"]["Value"]."<br/>";
    # code...
}
```

I used "H" for hour. That will show the format 09:55, if you want 9:55 use "G".
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. Now I see what I've gotten wrong in my code. I don't have much experience with JSON data, Is there a way to cut the LocalObservationDateTime to output only date and time. From this 2017-08-02T11:55:00+02:00 to something like this 2017-08-02 11:55:00.

Comment: @R1ddler Yes. But I would rather use another item for that. The `EpochTime` is UNIX time of the observation. If you have your timezone correct in the php settings date() should give you a good timestamp. Will update my answer to show you.